# error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct Array’

Tags: c, struct, declaration, definition, incomplete-type

I'm trying to enter a value into the struct I have in my header file. The value is given in the main file and is passed as an argument to a function. But I'm getting an error that says `error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct Array’ array->size = size;` The compiler is talking about the arrow in the line `array->size = size;` I have provided my files below.

Header.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//Include libraries used

struct Array {
  unsigned int size;
  unsigned int cap;
  int data;
};
//Declare struct Array

struct Array *newArray(unsigned int size, unsigned int cap);
```

function.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct Array *newArray(unsigned int size, unsigned int capacity ) {

  struct Array *array;

  array->size = size;

}
```

My main.c file has included the header file so I don't have it in my function.c file. It also calls the function newArray(5, 20), giving size the value of 5. How do I fix this error so I can have size in the struct equal to 5? Thanks, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: You need to set `array` before attempting to dereference it.  It's an undefined pointer value.

Comment: Furthermore, `struct Array` does not have member `width`. Don't be sloppy, but also post the exact code you are trying, don't show us errors that don't apply to the code you post.

Comment: @Cheatah I fixed the code, my apologies I entered the information incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the header `Header.h` where the structure is defined in the module `function.c` where the function is defined.

Otherwise in this function definition

```
struct Array *newArray(unsigned int width, unsigned int capacity ) {

  struct Array *array;

  array->width = width;

}
```

there is introduced the incomplete type specifier `struct Array`. And the compiler that compiles this module does not know whether the structure contains such a data members as `width`.

Though it seems your code snippet contains a typo because the structure definition does not contain the data member `width` and the compiler in the message refers to the data member `size`.

Also pay attention to that the pointer `array` is not initialized.

```
struct Array *array;
```

and has an indeterminate value.

So in any case even if you will include the structure definition this statement

```
array->width = width;
```

will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: I fixed my code , I had entered 'width', when it should have been 'size'

Comment: @Raswall It is not very important. I already explained the reason of the error message.